# Pass Int to enum and return a String

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'm trying to accomplish a task which is passing an integer value to enum, and return a specific String for the passed in integrer.

I'm using enum because the integers are known and each of them has a meaning. I have done the following:

```
enum Genre: String {
    case 28 = "Action"
    case 12 = "Adventure"
    case 16 = "Animation"
    case 35 = "Comedy"
    case 80 = "Crime"
}
```

**What I'm expecting**:  when passing one of the cases, I want to return the String association.

Please, if you have a question or need any further into, ask it in the comment.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a dictionary?

Comment: Nope, any thoughts on what is the best practice to use it here?

Comment: @MEnnabah Better you go with dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
enum Genre: Int {
    case action = 28
    case adventure = 12
    case animation = 16
    case comedy = 35
    case crime = 80
}
```

And use it like this

```
// enum as string 
let enumName = "\(Genre.action)" // `action`

// enum as int value 
let enumValue = Genre.action.rawValue // 28

// enum from int
let action = Genre.init(rawValue: 28)
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can not have `Int` as an `enum case` name.
Try this:

```
enum Genre: Int {
case action = 28, adventure = 12, animation = 16, comedy = 35, crime = 80

  func getString() -> String {
    switch self {
    case .action: return "Action"
    case .adventure: return "Adventure"
    case .animation: return "Animation"
    case .comedy: return "Comedy"
    case .crime: return "Crime"
    }
  }
}

let gener = Genre.action
print(gener.getString())//"Action"
```

And if you only know integer value, do this:

```
let gener1 = Genre(rawValue: 12)!
print(gener1.getString())//"Adventure"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating a dictionary that achieves the mapping you need, and creating constants for your keys to use them.

You can start by creating a class called `Constants` and putting the following constants in it:

```
static let action = 28
static let adventure = 12
// ... The rest of your constants.

// Then create a dictionary that contains the values:
static let genre = [action : "Action", adventure : "Adventure"] // And so on for the rest of your keys.
```

Then you could access any value you need using that dictionary like so:

```
let actionString = Constants.genre[Constants.action]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
let Genre = [28:"action",
12: "adventure",
16: "animation",
35: "comedy",
80: "crime"]
```

Example use:
    `let retValue = Genre[28]//"action"`

Here is playground demo:

[image]